# Rename levels of factors that contain symbols in R

Tags: r, r-factor

I have a data frame called `prueba` where I have a factor variable `ccaa` that contains the following levels:

```
x <- c("","Andalucia","Aragon","Asturias","Balears","Canarias","Cantabria",
       "Castilla Leon","Castilla Mancha","Catalu<f1>a","Ceuta","Comunitat Valenciana",
       "Extremadura","Galicia","Madrid","Melilla","Murcia","Navarra","Pa<ed>s Vasco",
       "Rioja")

prueba <- data.frame(cca = x)
levels(prueba$cca)

#  [1] ""                     "Andalucia"            "Aragon"               "Asturias"            
#  [5] "Balears"              "Canarias"             "Cantabria"            "Castilla Leon"       
#  [9] "Castilla Mancha"      "Catalu<f1>a"          "Ceuta"                "Comunitat Valenciana"
# [13] "Extremadura"          "Galicia"              "Madrid"               "Melilla"             
# [17] "Murcia"               "Navarra"              "Pa<ed>s Vasco"        "Rioja"
```

I am trying to rename those levels that contain symbols such as `"Catalu<f1>a"` and `"Pa<ed>s Vasco"`. I have tried several unsuccessful options:

Option 1: package `plyr` with function `revalue`

```
 prueba$ccaa = revalue(prueba$ccaa,c( "Pa<ed>s Vasco" = "Basque Country", "Catalu<f1>a" = "Catalonia"))
```

It yields the following error:

```
The following `from` values were not present in `x`: Pa<ed>s Vasco, Catalu<f1>a
```

Option 2:

```
levels(prueba$cca)[levels(prueba$cca)=="Catalu<f1>a"] <- "Catalonia"
levels(prueba$cca)[levels(prueba$cca)=="Pa<ed>s Vasco"] <- "Basque Country"
```

This works fine but does not rename the levels with the new labels

```
levels(prueba$ccaa)
#  [1] ""                     "Andalucia"            "Aragon"              
#  [4] "Asturias"             "Balears"              "Canarias"            
#  [7] "Cantabria"            "Castilla Leon"        "Castilla Mancha"     
#  [10] "Catalu<f1>a"          "Ceuta"                "Comunitat Valenciana"
# [13] "Extremadura"          "Galicia"              "Madrid"              
# [16] "Melilla"              "Murcia"               "Navarra"             
# [19] "Pa<ed>s Vasco"        "Rioja"
```

I don't understand why the levels do not get the right labels. Any suggestion about what may be happening?

Comment: Thanks for spotting. Still does not work

Comment: Yes, it works with other levels but not for the ones that I´m including. Maybe the problem is related to fact that the levels are including  > and < ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `recode` from `car`

```
library(car)
prueba$cca <- recode(prueba$cca, "'Pa<ed>s Vasco'='Basque Country';'Catalu<f1>a' = 'Catalonia'")
levels(prueba$cca)
#[1] ""                     "Andalucia"            "Aragon"               "Asturias"             "Balears"              "Basque Country"       "Canarias"            
#[8] "Cantabria"            "Castilla Leon"        "Castilla Mancha"      "Catalonia"            "Ceuta"                "Comunitat Valenciana" "Extremadura"         
#[15] "Galicia"              "Madrid"               "Melilla"              "Murcia"               "Navarra"              "Rioja"
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun. It still does not work although I have tried your code and it does, though. My guess referred to this problem may be referred to the fact that these levels (Catalonia and Basque Country) are associated with strange symbols such as accents (e.g. ñ and í) in the raw names and consequently R finds difficult to process them.

Comment: @Edu Based on the example you showed, it is working.